# Passing a type as a parameter

Tags: c

ETA: This is NOT about malloc(), or memory allocation, it's about passing a type as a parameter, like:

```
va_arg(l, char);
```

I'm using malloc() as a simple example.

This might be a stupid question, or perhaps I'm missing something.

Let's imagine I want to write a simple function that allocates some memory, not any particular type of memory but something more flexible.

Like, say I wanted 1,000 chars allocated and returned. So I'd like a function that I can call like this:

```
ptr = getMem(char, 1000);
```

Pasing the actual type as a parameter, which could be useful.

Now I know macros like va_arg() can do this:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", va_arg(l, char));
```

So I looked into it a bit, it's all rather vague. I found this:

```
type va_arg(va_list ap, type)
```

> Parameters

```
ap − This is the object of type va_list with information about the additional arguments and their retrieval state. This object should be initialized by an initial call to va_start before the first call to va_arg.

type − This is a type name. This type name is used as the type of the expression, this macro expands to.
```

You can see cleary the type for the first parameter is defined as `va_list`,
but the second parameter, the one I'm interested in - is simply specified as `type`.

So it started to bug me, I've been messing around with bum code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *getMem(type, int size) {
    return malloc(sizeof(type) * size);
}

int main(void)
{
    void    *mem;

    mem = getMem(1000, char);

    if (mem == NULL) {
        perror("malloc()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Memory allocated successfully!\n");
    free(mem);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I've been sniffing around include files trying to figure this out but to no avail, is there a way I can do this?

Sorry if it's a bit vague or nonsensical, but if va_arg() can do it I reckon I should be able to, also.

Much obliged.

Comment: You have to use preprocessor macros. For example `#define getMem(type, size) malloc((size) * sizeof(type))`

Comment: Well, I understand your point but I was simply trying to highlight an instance where it might be useful. I'm sure there would be more uses for it.

Comment: "Let's imagine I want to write a simple function that allocates some memory, not any particular type of memory but something more flexible." - You mean something like `malloc`?

Comment: @Olaf, no, not something like `malloc`, something that would return a `void *` type that could be used by anything `:)`

Comment: @Dani: Yes, thanks, this is about C, so stick with C. Not everyone want to bloat his code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, who needs type-safety. (I miss my 68K Assembler ...)

Comment: @Nunchy: Such a macro is of little ot no use, but complicates reading the code and is error-prone. Don't get too fancy with macros. K.I.S.S.!

Comment: To be honst I'm disappointed if this can only be done with a macro, and probably won't use it. Any particular reason why this cannot be done outwithe the pre-processor? there's absolutely no way?

Comment: @Nunchy: This is very basic stuff founded in the C language and its simplicity. If you are not happy with what a language provides, you might want to use a diferent one. As always: use the appropriate tool for your problem. If you only have a hammer ever problem looks like a nail.

Comment: Dude, I'm not complaining about anything. I don't think it's an unreasonable question.

Comment: also see [Generics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) although they are best used in conjunction with macros

Comment: "This is NOT about `malloc()`, or memory allocation, it's about passing a type as a parameter" --> OK, so it is not about `malloc()`.  The example posted only uses the _size_ of the type.  Do you have a need where the _type_ is passed/used and is not for determining the _size_.  Otherwise is seems simple enough to pass `sizeof(type)`

Comment: I'm asking a question about something that piqued my interest and I was curious about. Why is that a problem for some people? Contribute or don't.

Comment: BTW: `fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", va_arg(l, char));` is UB as `va_arg()` returns a value of type `char` which does not work with `"%s"`.

Comment: You're right -  next time I ask a question I'll simply ignore the responses. Let me show you..

Answer (score 2):

Do this with a CPP macro:

```
#define getMem(type, size) \
    malloc(sizeof(type) * size)
```

However, personally, I prefer this:

```
#define getMemOf(ptr, size) \
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * size)

// invoke with:
    getMemOf(ptr, 1000);
```

Comment: This is against common recommendations to use the LHS pointer's object to calculate the size. And it does not spare much typing.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - just to re-iterate, my initial example was nothing more than a means for me to illustrate my question. I'm not wanting to use this to write some malloc() wrapper. Much appreciated.

Comment: Doing assignment in a macro hides a lot of information and makes code using it hard to read and understand. Well, macros in general tend to do that, but the assignment is a really bad case IMO.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was editing the answer to add my second version, but [AFAICT] it also seems to fulfill Olaf's comment. How would you reconcile the two? I've used the idiom for quite a long time without too many problems. And, (e.g.) `gcc`'s source [last time I looked] is full of _huge_ multiline macros that do much more stuff. Ordinarily, I would use an all caps macro name. And, when I analyze source that has a macro [mine or anybody else's], I always look up the definition and never assume anything about what it does.

Answer (score 2):

`_Generic` in <strike>C99</strike> C11 may offer something close to OP's need.

Example: Code wants to assign the maximum value of a common integer type.

```
#define integer_max(X) _Generic((X), \
  unsigned long long: ULLONG_MAX, \
  long long: LLONG_MAX, \
  unsigned long: ULONG_MAX, \
  long: LONG_MAX, \
  unsigned: UINT_MAX, \
  int: INT_MAX, \
  unsigned short: USHRT_MAX, \
  short: SHRT_MAX, \
  unsigned char: UCHAR_MAX, \
  signed char: SCHAR_MAX, \
  char: CHAR_MAX, \
  _Bool: 1, \
  default: 1/0 \
  )

  // Here the _type_ of `x` is used by integer_max(), not its value.
  some_integer_type x = integer_max(x);
```

Comment: @Daniel Jour Agree, answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` does not need to know the type to work well, just the *size* of the type.

Should code want to insure no overflow in the size calculation, a check could be made.

```
void *getMem(size_t element_count, size_t type_size) {
  if (element_count > SIZE_MAX/type_size) return NULL;
  return malloc(element_count * size);
}

// usage example
size_t element_count, 
void * p = getMem(element_count, sizeof (char));
```

If one wants zero-ed memory, simple use `calloc()`

```
// usage example
size_t element_count, 
void * p = calloc(element_count, sizeof (char));
```

---

Recommend that code not use `void *` pointers and expresses a type like `char` separately.  Instead, declare a pointer with a non-`void` type.

```
#define ALLOCATE_ASSIGN(addr_ptr, count) (*(addr_ptr)=malloc(sizeof **(addr_ptr) * count))

some_type *mem;
ALLOCATE_ASSIGN(&mem, element_count);
```

Comment: Seriously: what benefit has this? (I could understand error-checking, but this?)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to end up doing this with `sizeof` anyway.  I just checked this in Visual Studio, and Microsoft defines it as (across several defines)

```
#define _INTSIZEOF(n)   ( (sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1) )
#define _crt_va_arg(ap,t)    ( *(t *)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)) )
#define va_arg _crt_va_arg
```

You can find these in vadefs.h.  Long story short, you're not going to get away from using sizeof somewhere, so you should just do it where it is most simple.  Personally I think that'd be just passing the size into your `getMem` function instead of the type will save you way more headache in the long run.

Comment: I appreciate the input, again it's not about malloc() it's about the use of a type as a parameter. Much obliged.